# Background image in TextView showing up transparent

Tags: android, xml, background-image, textview

I have a circle png that I put as a background image in a TextView. However, the image shows up transparent even when I tried setting the alpha level to "1". Is there something wrong I did in my XML code?

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeline_text_details_img"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

The circle png I want needs to be thick white like how it originally is

[image]

but instead it looks like this when I run it

[image]

Comment: What are the dimensions of the circle.png? It looks like it might be a rather large image scaled down quite a bit.

Comment: @MikeM. its 101 x 99 pixels. Do you think that's an issue?

Comment: Oh, that's near actual size? Nah, probably not that, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a shape `circle.xml` and place it in `drawable`.

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white"
        />

    <solid
        android:color="#000000"/>

</shape>
```

You can change the color scheme as you like.